# exception handler: Undefined index with implicit controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have Implicit Controller nammed MailingsController :

```
class MailingsController extends BaseController {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->beforeFilter('csrf', array('on' => 'post'));
        $lng = Config::get('app.locale');
        setlocale(LC_TIME, $lng ."_". strtoupper($lng));
    }

    public function getEmails() {
        die('hi');
    }

}
```

routes :

```
Route::controller('mailings', 'MailingsController');
```

view :

```
<a href="{{Config::get('app.locale')}}/mailings/emails" > ... </a>
```

When i click in a balise i got in response this error :

```
Error in exception handler: Undefined index: path (View: C:\wamp\www\tst\app\views\errors\404
.blade.php) in C:\wamp\www\tst\app\library\CustomUrlGenerator.php:76
```